# laravel5: Storing of checkboxes as tinyint(4) or boolean in mysql/DB

Tags: php, laravel

Looking for better execution of the below function, specifically dealing with checkboxes.

```
    /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(CreateUserRequest $request, $id)
{       

    $user = User::find($id);
    //TODO should be else where?
    $input = $request->all();
    if(isset($input['status'])) $input['status'] = 1;
        else $input['status'] = 0;
    $user->fill($input)->save();        
    return redirect('admin/users');     

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have and what you want?

Comment: The 3 lines below //TODO should be else where? as the controller should not be handling this kind of logic, plus if i have other forms with checkboxes they return "on" if selected or null if not. i just want a 1 or 0 in the db you see?

Comment: My controller is growing by the day, there has to be a better place to check returned inputs. `  if(isset($input['featured'])) $input['featured'] = 1;
   else $input['featured'] = 0;

  $ingredients_list = $request->input('ingredients_list');
  if(!isset($ingredients_list)) $ingredients_list = [];`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing fine, but you can test the value of status as the string 'yes'. Unchecked checkboxes just don't register anything, so you're going to be doing essentially the same thing. Assuming your checkbox input has value="yes", then:

```
$input = $request->all();
if($input['status'] === 'yes') $input['status'] = 1;
else $input['status'] = 0;
```

Pretty much no matter what, you're going to have to have the 'else' to define some value for the unchecked case. It's really just a matter of what you want to use for the checked value. You could even make it 1, but the unchecked case wouldn't be 0, you'd still need this condition to assign it.

If you're wanting to get the logic out of your controller, you might have tried setting the field default the field to 0 in your DDL, then in your model implementing the mutator (setter):

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function setStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['status'] = 1;
    }

}
```

The trouble here is that this won't get called if you don't have status in your input and you won't have it if the checkbox is unchecked. Thus it won't unset it if the user sets and unsets.

Hence, to the best of my knowledge, we all generate both true and false values for the input in the controller as a conventional practice. You're only real choice is what value you prefer to set on the input in the form.